# No sound after kernel update / ubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: sound, kernel, pulseaudio, alsa

I upgraded a couple of days ago to the latest kernel:

```
uname -a
Linux tirith 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Hadn't use the box much, but today i realized i have no sound.

I tried reinstalling alsa, alsa-utils, alsa-base, pulseaudio completly with no results. 
Alsamixer recognizes fine my sound hardware but no luck on making it work.

```
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel     HDA) (rev 40)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. M5A88-V EVO
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
    Memory at fe8f4000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Here is my alsa-info.sh output: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=ca02a907243342a21346fbd1f07118b28ab395c5

I also tried booting to the last "sound working" kernel 3.13.0-36 but no luck either. 
I really don't know what else to try here...

Any help will be much appreciated.

**[UPDATE]**

I installed pavucontrol and i can "see" VLC and Rythmbox sound playing.. but still no sound. Output hardware is correctly selected by default, no muted. 
Alsamixer also displays all volumes up, non muted. I even disabled "" just in case.

Please, its been more than 24hs, i'd really love to get my audio back

**[UPDATE 2]**
I ended up screwing my system playing with the LVM encription.. so i ended up making a full system reinstall. 
Sound is working now, so clearly it was a software issue.. 
Too bad ill never know what it was..

Thanks for the guys who answered.

Answer (score 1):

- In pavucontrol , "setting" tab, test various  profile , as "surround" mode is enabled (as shown in the alsa-info) .
- If no success, test directly alsa audio layer  running in a terminal  `speaker-test -c 2 -D plughw:0,0` or  `speaker-test -c 2 -D plughw:0,1`
  if your hear noise, it means that pulseaudio is the problem, in which case a further test would be to disable it , running  this 3 commands:
  `mkdir ~/.pulse`
  `echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf`
  `pulseaudio -k`
  then retest using a normal audio player .

Comment: laugeo thanks for your answer but no luck. I tried both commands and no sound came out. Also tried all profiles on pavucontrol with same results. It is a surround system (5.1)

Comment: did you reboot after running the 3 commands disabling pulseaudio ? run again alsamixer in a terminal , double check fader level and mute state, run again both speaker-test